# NULL return value of type QList<float*>

Tags: c++, qt, null, default, qlist

I would like to return a default Null value for a method returning a QList<float*> (in case processing fails, I want to return).

How to build a Null QList<float*> properly?

Comment: QList<float*> *list = null;

Comment: @Blood: That's a pointer, not a `QList` value. You'd also need to somehow create a value to point to, when you don't want to return "null".

Comment: @Blood, [what's `null`?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77f5589ec71bc79f)

Comment: If processing fails, you also want to return an error message I guess. => throw an exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, there's no such thing as a "null value" for non-pointer types. Options include:

- Throw an exception on failure
- Return an empty list, if that can never be a valid result
- Return a nullable wrapper type, like `boost::optional<QList>` or `std::pair<bool, QList>`

Answer (score 1):

return a pointer to a QList then test it for null pointer, i think this is what your asking anyway, sorry if i misinterpreted

```
void someClass::test()
{
    std::shared_ptr<QList<float> > testList = doSomething()
    if(testList == nulllptr)
    {
        // Then its null
    }
    else
    {
       // Do whatever you want with it
    }
}

std::shared_ptr<QList<float>> someClass::doSomething()
{
    std::shared_ptr<QList<float>> someList; // = NULL at the moment 

    if(weWantValues) // Lets just pretend this bool knows if we want values 
    {
        someList = std::make_shared<QList<float>(); // now a shared pointer to a list
        // Populate with whatever values you want. use ".get()" or "->" to access list
    }

    // this may be null or populated so check if it == nullptr before using
    // Like we do in the function above
    return someList;
}
```

Comment: So what should it point to when you don't want to return `nullptr`? A dynamically allocated list, which the caller must remember to delete? Or a static list which might be unexpectedly modified by a subsequent call to the function? Or something else?

Comment: There you go let me know if this makes is clearer say if it doesnt :)

Comment: So now you'd better document that the caller is responsible for deletion, and fix the memory leak. Or return a smart pointer. Dynamic allocation isn't something to do lightly in C++. (Also, you'll need to explicitly initialise the pointer to be null, otherwise it will have a garbage value).

Comment: better?, now were using smart pointers (shared pointers) which handle their own delete, am i right in saying this?

Comment: also @mikeSeymour im aware `boost::optional` is the best thing here probably but i was trying to offer a library free alternative

Comment: AngryDuck: Yes, it looks correct now. It's rather less efficient than returning a value - maybe that's an issue, maybe it isn't.

Comment: `optional` is only really necessary if the type can't be (cheaply) default-constructed. Something like `pair<bool,QList>` is fine otherwise, avoiding the allocation overhead without requiring non-standard libraries.

Comment: Yea i do see your point, but each to thier own and might help with some understanding of pointers and smart pointers etc so cant hurt as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return {}` instead of nullptr, like this:

```
QList<QObject *> getModel(int id)
{
    if (id < 0)
        return {};

    return m_myModel->model();
}
```